# How to avoid conflicts caused when doing string replace multiple times

Tags: javascript, date, replace, formatting

I wanted an easy simple way to format a `Date` through my whole application.
So I wrote a function for it.

```
Date.prototype.format = function (template)
{
    let str = template.replace('yyyy', this.getFullYear());
    str = str.replace('mm', (this.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'));
    str = str.replace('dd', this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'));
    str = str.replace('HH', this.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0'));
    str = str.replace('ii', this.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'));
    str = str.replace('ss', this.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'));
    str = str.replace('ddd', this.toLocaleString(window.navigator.language, { weekday: 'short' }));
    str = str.replace('dddd', this.toLocaleString(window.navigator.language, { weekday: 'long' }));
    return str;
};
```

I was inspired by PHP and some other programming languages that have this kind of formatting functions built in.
However the problem is, the `dd`, `ddd` and `dddd` replacements conflict with each other.
In other words, a template string like `ddd dd-mm-yyyy` should be *Sun 05-11-2023*, but what I get instead is *05d 05-11-2023*. I know what logic causes this, but I cannot come with a solution by myself. I probably have to use some specific Regex, but I don't know how to handle it.
I've had this same kind of problem before.
How should I change my code and could someone explain it a little bit?

Comment: replace the longer patterns first.

Comment: When adding functions to the prototype of a system class, it's better to use `Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, "format", { ... })`.

Comment: @pilchard I thought of this. But I actually want to have a solution for different future string replacement cases.

Comment: You might want to read through [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript) which isn't a duplicate per se, but includes 13 years of discussion of this topic.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression at all. Just parse the format string character by character until you get something that doesn't match a token or reach the end of the string. Then use the preceding characters as the token and use the odd character as the first of the next token. If you get a character that doesn't match a token at all, pass it through as–is.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conflicts in string replacements, perform the replacements in an order that prevents smaller placeholders from being altered by longer ones and use a regular expression to match the entire placeholder.

**Replace longer placeholders first** and **use boundary checks** in regular expressions **to ensure complete matches**.

```js
Date.prototype.format = function (template) {
    const replacements = {
        'yyyy': this.getFullYear(),
        'mm': (this.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
        'dd': this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
        'HH': this.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
        'ii': this.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
        'ss': this.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
        'dddd': this.toLocaleString(window.navigator.language, { weekday: 'long' }),
        'ddd': this.toLocaleString(window.navigator.language, { weekday: 'short' }),
    };

    return Object.keys(replacements).reduce((str, key) => {
        const regex = new RegExp("\\b" + key + "\\b", "g");
        return str.replace(regex, replacements[key]);
    }, template);
};

const today = new Date();
console.log(today.format('ddd dd-mm-yyyy')); // Usage example
```

Comment: This relies on key order which isn't guaranteed, the regex is actually doing the heavy lifting here.

Comment: `window.navigator.language` can be simply `'default'`.